# jqGrid and jqPivot: How to replace value of pivot column by input tag?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I'm using jqGrid with the jqPivot.

My data:

```
 var data = [{
            Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mary", KindOfCare: 'Birthday', value: 1, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mary", KindOfCare: 'Christmas', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mary", KindOfCare: 'New Year', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mia", KindOfCare: 'Birthday', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mia", KindOfCare: 'Christmas', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
           Account: "Tom", Contact: "Mia", KindOfCare: 'New Year', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        },
        {
            Account: "Anna", Contact: "David", KindOfCare: 'Birthday', value: 1, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Anna", Contact: "David", KindOfCare: 'Christmas', value: 1, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Anna", Contact: "David", KindOfCare: 'New Year', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Selena", Contact: "Bieber", KindOfCare: 'Birthday', value: 0, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
            Account: "Selena", Contact: "Bieber", KindOfCare: 'Christmas', value: 1, notes: 'Birthday'
        }, {
           Account: "Selena", Contact: "Bieber", KindOfCare: 'New Year', value: 1, notes: 'Birthday'
        }];
```

I want replace value of pivot column by input tag, ex: if value = 1 then return checkbox checked, and if value = 0, return checkbox

[image]

Any way to do it?

Comment: my plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/WfRtXnUk9KqarOfdp63L?p=preview. I try return '<input  class="center" type="checkbox" disabled />' but not working, result return NaN

Comment: Your pivot setup is copy/paste from another code and does not have anything to do with your actual data. In order to help you will need to set it according to your data

Comment: @TonyTomov, I updated my plunk, please try again

Comment: @TonyTomov, can you replace 1 by checkbox **checked** and 0 by checkbox **not checked**

Comment: Since you use free-jqGrid I can not tell you what are the parameters passed to the function - in Guriddo jqGrid it is very easy and you can read the [docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/pivotgrid/#aggregates) what to do, but in you may want not to use the data as number in order to set input as you suggested

Comment: @TonyTomov, thanks so much. I will try another ways

Comment: Your code will work if you disable template to be a number and add a logic in the custom function like `if(value=='1') { return '<input.. checked/>'} else { return '<input... />';}`

Comment: I update my plunk with your suggestion, but result return NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work if you set in template empty string. Please look into the free jqGrid docs what is tempale and the possible values the parameter can accept

```
                aggregates: [
                    { member: "KindOfCare",
                    template: "",
                      aggregator: function (options) {
                        //console.log(options);
                        //return options.item.value;
                        if(options.item.value == 1){
                          return '<input class="center" type="checkbox" checked disabled />';
                        }
                        else{
                          return '<input class="center" type="checkbox" disabled />';

                        }
                      } 

                    }
                ]
```

Comment: I removed _template_  but not make it empty string, so it wrong. Thanks for your solutions. that's great !

Comment: Thank you. Glad to help.

Comment: a small question more: Is there any way to add colum *Notes*  to the end of grid, to make it look like picture above?

Comment: Sorry , in this case I can not help. I know the answer only for Guriddo jqGrid

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your help!